# CARTO update existing table from external MySQL database

Tags: carto, api, php, mysql

I would like my Carto data to be updated, using external data (MySQL database, I run and manage locally using PHP scripts), so that the Carto table gets updated with the most recent data, whenever the map gets loaded.

Is it possible?